# laravel5 -> Select 100 results randomly from a returned result set

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to create a function that after i run a search i can return a number specified in the results from the result set randomly.

The search works just fine. But i need to be able to select from that result set based on user input (example user wants to get 100 records from the returned result set).

Here is my code for the query

```
class Business extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'businesses_old';

    /*
     * Return search result on bussinesses
     * @param $params array
     * @return mixed
     */

    public static function search($params){
        $businesses = self::query();
        if(isset($params['business']) && $params['business']!=''){
            $businesses->where('name','like', "%".$params['business']."%");
            /*$businesses->orWhere('contact_first_name','like', "%".$params['business']."%");
            $businesses->orWhere('contact_last_name','like', "%".$params['business']."%");
            $businesses->orWhere('email','like', "%".$params['business']."%");
            $businesses->orWhere('address_1','like', "%".$params['business']."%");
            $businesses->orWhere('address_2','like', "%".$params['business']."%");*/
            $businesses->orWhere('website','like', "%".$params['business']."%");
            /*$businesses->orWhere('city','like', "%".$params['business']."%");*/
            $businesses->orWhere('description','like', "%".$params['business']."%");
            /*$businesses->orWhere('state','like', "%".$params['business']."%");*/

        }
        $businesses->orderBy('name','ASC');
        return $businesses->paginate(20);
    }

    public static function InRandom($businesses) {
        $random = inRandomOrder($businesses);
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the search controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\Business;

class SearchController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display search form
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function index(){        
        return view('search/index');
    }

    /**
     * Display search results
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function indexHandle(){        
        $params=[];       
        if($business = Input::get('business')){
            $params['business']=$business;            
        }
        $businesses='';
        if(!empty($params)){
            $businesses=Business::search($params);
        }else{
            return redirect('/search');
        }

        return view('search/result', compact('businesses','business'));
    }

}
```

Comment: Wait. Let's assume you have 1000rows in table and want to get 100 of them. Do you want to get 100 results from randomized table (pagination will not work properly) or paginate table and return every 100 items (every page) with randomized order?

Comment: basically i want the user to search our DB. They see how many results are returned. Then they can request to see 100 randomly from the returned data set.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you have to change this line

```
$businesses->orderBy('name','ASC');
```

With this

```
$businesses->inRandomOrder();
```

This will shuffle record from **entire** table and then you are getting 20 records (for current page) from randomized result.

**But**
pagination won't work now as you expecting, cause every time you run `search` function your randomized result will be different.

Answer (score 0):

This should work with MySQL, just change the LIMIT to fit your needs:

```
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: The initial search does work. The trick is that i need the user to specify how many they randomly want to get and then return a random number from the result set

Comment: You should clarify your question